# OPC Server add items error HResult

Tags: c#, opc

I am writing a code which reads the data from the OPC server.

```
public void setOPC()
{
            int count = 1;

            try
            {
                opcServer = new OPCServer();
                opcServer.Connect("OPCTechs.SiemensNet30DA", "");
                opcServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupIsActive = true;
                opcServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupDeadband = 0f;
                opcServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupUpdateRate = 10;

                opcGroup = opcServer.OPCGroups.Add("MP");
                opcGroup.IsSubscribed = false;
                opcGroup.OPCItems.DefaultIsActive = false;

                int[] h = new int[844];

                for (int i = 69; i >= 60; i--, count++)
                {
                    h[count] = opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("HH1001.B" + i, count).ServerHandle;
                }

                for (int i = 69; i >= 60; i--, count++)
                {
                    h[count] = opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("GF1001OP190.B" + i, count).ServerHandle;
                }
}
```

In the above code, as it executes the second loop & reaches the line

```
h[count] = opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("GF1001OP190.B" + i, count).ServerHandle;
```

it gives the error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x0040007
```

If it executes the first loops `AddItem` successfully, why it is giving problem with the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("GF1001OP190.B" + i, count).ServerHandle;
```

It will get the ServerHandle on OPCItems but not on a particular item. But you are supposed to get the ServerHandle on a particular item but not on the entire Items.

Try

```
opcGroup.OPCItems.AddItem("GF1001OP190.B" + i, count);
h[count] = opcGroup.OPCItems[count].ServerHandle;
```